# Disable lazy load in lagest contentful paint in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, lazy-loading

I found [this 2 year old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326178/19838182) that essentially counts the `<img>` and removes the loading attribute where the count =1 and implemented via snippets plugin for Wordpress.

Unfortunately GTMetrix is still flagging "don't lazy load LCP" and when I inspect the image in my browsers I still see the attribute loading="lazy" for the 1st (and every) image on every post.

I suspected it was counting the site logo in the header as the 1st image but it too has loading="lazy" so it seems that the code isn't working at all.

- Wordpress 6.0.1
- Theme: Hello Elementor Child
- Elementor + Elementor Pro
- JetEngine for custom post type
- Imagify for webP conversion & optimization

I'm not running any lazy-loading plugin and don't want to disable wordpress's global lazy load for all images, just the one above the fold in the LCP.

Snippet I'm running:

```
/* Remove lazy load first image */
function add_responsive_class($content)
{
    if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_front_page() || is_home() ) 
    {
        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));
        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $img = $imgs[0];
        if ($imgs[0] == 1) 
        { // Check first if it is the first image
            $img->removeAttribute( 'loading' );
            $html = $document->saveHTML();
            return $html;
        }
        else 
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');
```

If anyone can help me understand why this doesn't work on my site or has a different solution I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Better if you give a higher priority to your filter. It could be that you try to remove something that still doesn't exist.
Elementor is responsible for the output of the image, and it may filter the content after your filter and add the loading parameter after your filter.

As a side note, you can't know if all the first images are always visible. Imagine for example an accordion, or something similar. I don't say that your script is not useful, but that it doesn't always guarantee the best results. Be sure you don't have hidden images. This may also be the cause of the failure of your script. Maybe you are removing the loading parameter to the first hidden images.

In the case of a hidden image, it would be better if they are lazy-loaded.
But if in your specific case, you are sure, then you should not have issues. In that case, check the priority of the filter.

You can also give the possibility in the Elementor editor to remove the lazy load. You can use this code:

```
add_action( 'elementor/element/image/section_image/before_section_end', function( $element, $args ) {
    $element->start_injection( [
        'at' => 'after',
        'of' => 'link',
    ] );
    $element->add_control(
        'my_image_lazy_loading',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Lazy Loading','lazy-load-control-for-elementor' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
      'default' => 'lazy',
            'options' => [
                'lazy' => __( 'Lazy load','lazy-load-control-for-elementor' ),
                'no_lazy' => __( 'Do not lazy load','lazy-load-control-for-elementor' ),
            ],
        ]
    );
    $element->end_injection();
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'elementor/widget/render_content', function( $content, $widget ){
  if( $widget->get_name() === 'image' ){
    $settings = $widget->get_settings();
    if( isset( $settings['my_image_lazy_loading'] ) && 'no_lazy' === sanitize_text_field( $settings['my_image_lazy_loading'] ) ){
      $content = str_replace( ' loading="lazy"','',$content );
    }
  }
  return $content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Then the user can decide which images should not be lazy loaded.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Could you add the option to remove the lazy load from the section's image too?